# a moderator closed my question is any one watching.

Tags: discussion

I do not have requisite previlieges to post many links to my questions my genuine question was blocked be this sites moderator is any one watching.
The internal IPs of apache vhost configuration file which I was posting were treaated as links

https://serverfault.com/questions/229628/using-apache-as-a-front-end-to-tomcat-application

Moderators should behave more sensibly.I am new to this forum.How do you say the question is not real when your forum is not allowing me to post links to snapshots so that some one can understand what I asked.

Comment: Technically, Stack Overflow isn't a discussion forum, it's a Q&A site. Moderators are very active so this will be picked up on. For more information on the Stack Overflow network, check out the FAQ http://serverfault.com/faq

Comment: Immediately below "Closed as not a real question..." it states "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form." Surely that's got to be a bit of a clue as to why it was closed.

Comment: This is a very wrong way of forcing your choices on person asking question.Only if your forum is useful enough the person is going to come back and start participating in discussions learn to compete.Forcing people to make more post just to have some more disk usage does not makes any sense.

Comment: Why is it wrong? This site is reasonably open in how it works, but at the end of the day its owned and operated by someone and they get to make the rules - or at least set the boundaries within which we can make our own. If you have a point that can be properly explained and addressed then it might get some support (and evenutally then might be accepted) but simply saying "The site isn't what I thought it was and that's not fair" isn't going to hope, and I'm afraid that is what your reply here sounds like.

Comment: we've mentioned several times now: *This is not a forum*! This is a Q&A Site, if you're looking for a forum, look elsewhere. There's an [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq) that explains all this too.

Answer (score 17):

I think that the problem with your question is that you don't explain what is wrong, then when someone asks you what is wrong, you tell people to look at the site to see that it's "not working".

Serverfault wants to have questions that will be useful for everyone, not just you.  Once you fix your site, will that URL you linked even exist anymore?  If someone else has a problem like yours, would they even be able to tell that you had the same problem or what you did to fix it would fix their problem as well?

It's not possible for anyone to fix your problem by looking at broken images.  I would rewrite your question to explain *how* the URLs are broken, and *what those URLs need to look like in order for it to work*.  For instance: "the header image says `/banana.jpg` when it needs to say `/portal/banana.jpg`."  Then we can see what needs to be done, and other people whose page is trying to link to `/banana.jpg` can see your question and realize that they have the same problem you do and can fix it in the same way.

Comment: The link which you are saying is I posted is not posted  by me it was edited by a user.Here is the link to my configuration http://pastebin.com/L32D6ii5
I am not saying to look at broken images  the problem is I am not even able to give a link to the doc which I am trying and getting downvoted each time I am trying to post with a reference to my question.

Comment: Your original question said that the images were broken but you never said what the URLs need to be in order for them to be "fixed".  I have no clue where your images are supposed to go, so I have no way of telling you what you need to change in your configuration to make them go there.

Comment: I could not post any link to any of my site or configuration because your forum policy does not allow to do so that does not mean my question was not genuine this is a third  class forum where I have not got a single answer.

Answer (score 8):

You develop the necessary privileges by helping out other people instead of whining about moderation.  Everyone using the site started from the same place that you did, and we all faced the same limitations with our first few questions.

Comment: How does it answer my question.

Comment: @Registered User, please take a few moments to read the FAQ, as others have already suggested.

Comment: this is a very wrong way of forcing your choices on person asking question.Only if your forum is useful enough the person is going to come back and start participating in discussions but when you kill interest of people like this it wont work.

Comment: @Registered User - unfortunately for you tens of thousands of other users seem to manage to understand and get on with the system to everyone's benefit.

Answer (score 7):

What often causes confusion is the perception that somehow your question is being judged as 'not important' - please trust this is not the case. Your (unpaid, volunteer) readers (the users of serverfault) have been promised (by the founders, the mods, and the high rep members of the community) that the questions on the site will be filtered & edited so as to provide content that is reusable (will hopefully benefit people with the same problem in the future) as well as answerable.

My suggestion is that you dissect your larger problem and attempt to post distinct, answerable questions that will hopefully give you a better understanding of the problem, once answered.

The question you linked actually has multiple questions within it. Long-time users of SF know that this will lead to a long & confused Q&A session that benefits nobody. Trust me, I've posted this kind of question, myself - then gone back and pared the question back (or just reposted a newer, simpler question) because nobody was interested in answering my monstrous lump of non-understanding.

I hope that clears things up a bit.

Comment: It amazes me how diplomatic you can be, Kara...  Bravo!

Comment: The bright side of my tendency to have made just about every possible mistake?  ;)  (but shucks, thanks!)